# Search Ranking of Results on Relational Data

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am creating a question & answer system and I want to perform searches using Azure Search from a single text box. Originally I was thinking of placing the answers and questions in different indices, so that each index only described one concept of data. However, with this model I have no clue how to perform a search with ranking based on both question data and answer data.

Is the only way to do this by storing all the items in the same index? I know Lucene and Elastic Search have the concept of Join Queries and Parent-Child mapping's for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are implementing a full-text search experience using Azure Search, and your question is NOT about relational database schema design. If that's the case, denormalizing your questions and answers into a single index is probably the right thing to do - your users will be able to find relevant content, whether related to questions or to answers. You can still set up separate scoring profiles for situations where you need to boost either question- or answer-related fields in your index schema.

Comment: cool, do you know if using a graphdb like neo4j or another search service can be an alternative solution? Something like search for relevant questions AND answers and let the relevancy flow from nodes to their parents etc.

Comment: also I assume for concurrency reasons I should replicate my data elsewhere? Since I likely will have a collection of answers per a question, I would need to ensure that two users submitting an answer at the same time does not destroy one of the users answers (during a collection merge).

Comment: I have no experience with graph dbs. There are of course other search technologies such as Elasticsearch or Solr. Elasticsearch can model parent / child relationship to some extent. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "relevancy flow". If you denormalize questions and answers, there's no need to model hierarchical relationships at all,  hence no concern with concurrent updates (assuming users can only add answers, not edit / remove questions).